# What Oracle expects of us?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

### RESUME

There is a time I have been studying the new JavaFX technology, and I've been faced with some barriers in creating custom controls. I learned how to use CSS to customize my controls, and then I came across the case of customizing controls using [Skin](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/Skin.html) and [SkinBase](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html).

Seen such resources, it was easy to initiate and complete the creation of new controls with visual and specific functionalities. However, personalization, that is, the visual and functional editing of existing controls on JavaFX library becomes somewhat more complicated. In many cases the programmer is forced to use resources that are only available in [private packages from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) (com.sun ...), which would become a bad practice, resulting in the production of software not maintainable.

Imagine the example where we want to customize the [ScrollBar](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html) control. It is possible to change its appearance completely using CSS. However, the desire of adding new behaviors to such control involves creating a new Theme from ZERO, without any reuse of [ScrollBarSkin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/ScrollBarSkin.java), because it is in the private Oracle package. This forces the programmer having to reimplement the logics that have already been implemented, such as the positioning of thumb, the update of values, what happens when you click the track, among many other things. In stubbornness to create a subtype of ScrollBarSkin it is seen that there are many important methods that have been encapsulated as not being overwritten, leaving you to have to compulsorily reimplement the existing logic.

What appears, at least, is that many important components for customizing a control are caged, causing you to have to use a single path to reach them (still limited).

### EXAMPLE (from theory to practice)

To illustrate what I mean by this and emphasize in the conclusion of this question in this community, we will briefly try to customize the ScrollBar existing in JavaFX package. My intention is to create a scrollbar to look like this:

[LINK1](http://s23.postimg.org/u2axiv1d7/scrollbars.jpg) & [LINK2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4jQG.jpg)

With regard to the behavior of the scrollbar, while clicking on it’s arrows, they should move a little, returning to their positions when the mouse button is released. When you pass the mouse over the thumb and arrows, they should light up. By clicking in the track or pushing any of our scrollbar arrows, the thumb must moves smoothly, in animated form and not abruptly.

So let's start with our experiment. First, let's create a CSS file that will serve as a definition of some appearances:

```
.scroll-bar {
-fx-skin: "packageA.packageB.ScrollBarSkin2";

-fx-background-color: rgb(66,64,64);
-fx-border-color: rgb(96,96,98);
-fx-border-width: 1px;
}

.scroll-bar > .thumb {
-fx-background-insets: 5 0 5 0;
-fx-shape: "M0 0c3,0 7,0 10,0l0 6c-3,0 -7,0 -10,0l0 -6z";
}

.scroll-bar > .increment-button > .increment-arrow , 
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow , 
.scroll-bar > .thumb {
-fx-background-color: rgb(254,254,254);
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ BUTTONS */

.scroll-bar:horizontal > .increment-button ,
.scroll-bar:horizontal > .decrement-button ,
.scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button , 
.scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button {
-fx-padding: 4px;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal > .increment-button:hover ,
.scroll-bar:horizontal > .decrement-button:hover ,
.scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button:hover , 
.scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button:hover {
-fx-background-color: null;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ BUTTONS SHAPES */

.scroll-bar:horizontal > .increment-button > .increment-arrow {
-fx-shape: "m -745.01097,-1519.0664 -156.95606,90.6186 -156.95607,90.6186 0,-181.2372 0,-181.2372 156.95608,90.6186 z";
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
-fx-shape: "m -1455.5694,-1550.495 153.1056,-88.3956 153.1056,-88.3955 0,176.7911 0,176.7911 -153.1056,-88.3955 z";
}

.scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button > .increment-arrow {
-fx-shape: "m -1334.2856,-2204.9669 85.446,147.9968 85.446,147.9968 -170.892,0 -170.8921,0 85.446,-147.9968 z";
}

.scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
-fx-shape: "m -1234.2856,-1096.134 -94.0582,-162.9135 -94.0582,-162.9136 188.1164,0 188.1163,0 -94.0582,162.9136 z";
}
```

Observing our CSS file, we can see that we chose one of the 3 existing ways to connect our control to our skin, and we use the definition of [-fx-skin](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control) property in our CSS file. Now we need to link our CSS file created with our control. This is done in Java code where we just have to set the CSS style sheet our control:

```
scrollBar.getStylesheets().setAll(this.getClass().getResource("scroll-bar-style.css").toExternalForm());
```

> **Note**: To run the example, you need to have a test class with a main
>   method to create and place a ScrollBar in a scene graph.

We already have our control linked to our Skin, but we have not really created the Skin. Creating or editing controls takes into account that the controls themselves, ie, the objects that extend [Control](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/Control.html), are considered part of the model of the [MVC pattern, existing in JavaFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/UI+Controls+Architecture). The part of the control and visualization is originally divided (do not know for what reason) into two parts. One, called the Skin, and the other, called Behavior. Both are existing interfaces in JavaFX with Skin representing the Visualization part, and Behavior being the part of Control. Unfortunately (do not know why!) Behavior is considered a private part of the JavaFX package, so the users developers of JavaFX are pushed to treat the part of Visualization and Control inside the Skin, which would be the part initially set for Visualization only. Having said all these strange things, let's create our Skin class:

```
// Public packages.
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Duration;

// ... And here we have a private package.
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollBarSkin;

public class ScrollBarSkin2 extends ScrollBarSkin
{
// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                 INSTANCES
// #########################################################################################################

// SUBSTRUCTURES

private StackPane thumb;
private StackPane track;
private Region incButton;
private Region decButton;
private Region incArrow;
private Region decArrow;

// EFFECTS

private DropShadow drop_thumb;
private DropShadow drop_inc;
private DropShadow drop_dec;

// ANIMATIONS

private BindableTransition aniTran_thumbDrop;
private BindableTransition aniTran_incDrop;
private BindableTransition aniTran_decDrop;

private TranslateTransition aniTran_setaInc;
private TranslateTransition aniTran_setaDec;

// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                              CONSTRUCTORS
// #########################################################################################################

public ScrollBarSkin2(ScrollBar scrollbar) 
{
    super(scrollbar);

    this.thumb = (StackPane) this.getSkinnable().lookup(".thumb");
    this.track = (StackPane) this.getSkinnable().lookup(".track");  
    this.incButton = (Region) this.getSkinnable().lookup(".increment-button");
    this.decButton = (Region) this.getSkinnable().lookup(".decrement-button");
    this.incArrow = (Region) this.getSkinnable().lookup(".increment-arrow");
    this.decArrow = (Region) this.getSkinnable().lookup(".decrement-arrow");

    this.configureSubstructures();
    this.addEvents();
}

/** Sets the substructures obtained.*/
protected void configureSubstructures()
{
    // ####################
    //        THUMB
    // ####################

    this.drop_thumb = new DropShadow();
    this.drop_thumb.setRadius(0);
    this.drop_thumb.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    this.thumb.setEffect(this.drop_thumb);
    this.aniTran_thumbDrop = new BindableTransition(Duration.millis(250));

    // ####################
    //   INCREMENT BUTTON
    // ####################

    this.drop_inc = new DropShadow();
    this.drop_inc.setRadius(0);
    this.drop_inc.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    this.incArrow.setEffect(this.drop_inc);
    this.aniTran_incDrop = new BindableTransition(Duration.millis(250));

    // ####################
    //   DECREMENT BUTTON
    // ####################

    this.drop_dec = new DropShadow();
    this.drop_dec.setRadius(0);
    this.drop_dec.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    this.decArrow.setEffect(this.drop_dec);
    this.aniTran_decDrop = new BindableTransition(Duration.millis(250));

    // ####################
    //        ARROWS
    // ####################

    this.aniTran_setaInc = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(100) , this.incArrow);
    this.aniTran_setaDec = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(100) , this.decArrow);

    if(this.getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
    {
        this.aniTran_setaInc.setFromX(this.incArrow.getLayoutX());
        this.aniTran_setaInc.setToX(this.incArrow.getLayoutX() + 2);

        this.aniTran_setaDec.setFromX(this.incArrow.getLayoutX());
        this.aniTran_setaDec.setToX(this.incArrow.getLayoutX() - 2);
    }
    else if(this.getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL)
    {
        this.aniTran_setaInc.setFromY(this.incArrow.getLayoutY());
        this.aniTran_setaInc.setToY(this.incArrow.getLayoutY() - 2);

        this.aniTran_setaDec.setFromY(this.incArrow.getLayoutY());
        this.aniTran_setaDec.setToY(this.incArrow.getLayoutY() + 2);
    }
}

/** Adds events animations. Here we also have the logic part.*/
protected void addEvents()
{
    // ####################
    //        THUMB
    // ####################

    thumb.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(aniTran_thumbDrop.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_thumbDrop.setRate(1);
                aniTran_thumbDrop.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_thumbDrop.setRate(1);
            }
        }
    });

    thumb.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(aniTran_thumbDrop.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_thumbDrop.setRate(-1);
                aniTran_thumbDrop.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_thumbDrop.setRate(-1);
            }
        }
    });

    this.aniTran_thumbDrop.fractionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable , Number oldValue , Number newValue) 
        {
            drop_thumb.setRadius(4 * newValue.doubleValue());
        }
    });

    // ####################
    //   INCREMENT BUTTON
    // ####################

    incButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(aniTran_incDrop.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_incDrop.setRate(1);
                aniTran_incDrop.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_incDrop.setRate(1);
            }
        }
    });

    incButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(aniTran_incDrop.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_incDrop.setRate(-1);
                aniTran_incDrop.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_incDrop.setRate(-1);
            }
        }
    });

    this.aniTran_incDrop.fractionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable , Number oldValue , Number newValue) 
        {
            drop_inc.setRadius(4 * newValue.doubleValue());
        }
    });

    // ####################
    //   DECREMENT BUTTON
    // ####################

    decButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(aniTran_decDrop.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_decDrop.setRate(1);
                aniTran_decDrop.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_decDrop.setRate(1);
            }
        }
    });

    decButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(aniTran_decDrop.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_decDrop.setRate(-1);
                aniTran_decDrop.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_decDrop.setRate(-1);
            }
        }
    });

    this.aniTran_decDrop.fractionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable , Number oldValue , Number newValue) 
        {
            drop_dec.setRadius(4 * newValue.doubleValue());
        }
    });

    // ####################
    //   INCREMENT ARROW
    // ####################

    this.incButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if(aniTran_setaInc.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_setaInc.setRate(1);
                aniTran_setaInc.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_setaInc.setRate(1);
            }
        }
    });

    this.incButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if(aniTran_setaInc.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_setaInc.setRate(-1);
                aniTran_setaInc.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_setaInc.setRate(-1);
            }
        }
    });

    // ####################
    //   DECREMENT ARROW
    // ####################

    this.decButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if(aniTran_setaDec.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_setaDec.setRate(1);
                aniTran_setaDec.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_setaDec.setRate(1);
            }
        }
    });

    this.decButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if(aniTran_setaDec.getStatus() != Animation.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                aniTran_setaDec.setRate(-1);
                aniTran_setaDec.play();
            }
            else
            {
                aniTran_setaDec.setRate(-1);
            }
        }
    });

    // ####################
    //        TRACK
    // ####################

    this.getSkinnable().valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener()
    {
        @Override public void invalidated(Observable observable) 
        {
            System.out.println("ScrollBar value is invalid: " + getSkinnable().getValue());
        }
    });

    this.getSkinnable().valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable , Number oldValue , Number newValue) 
        {
            System.out.printf("ScrollBar value changed! - [OLD: %f , NEW: %f] %n" , 
                    oldValue.doubleValue() , newValue.doubleValue() );
        }
    });

    this.track.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println("Track pressed!");
        }
    });

    ChangeListener<Number> listenerThumb = new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable , Number oldValue, Number newValue) 
        {
            System.out.println("Thumb moved!");
        }
    };

    thumb.layoutXProperty().addListener(listenerThumb);
    thumb.layoutYProperty().addListener(listenerThumb);
    thumb.translateXProperty().addListener(listenerThumb);
    thumb.translateYProperty().addListener(listenerThumb);
}

@Override protected void handleControlPropertyChanged(String p) 
{
    System.out.println("Beginning.: " + p);

    super.handleControlPropertyChanged(p);

    System.out.println("End: " + p);
}
}
```

As you can see, we insist on creating a subtype of ScrollBarSkin, a private implementation of JavaFX (com.sun ...) package. I also want to make clear that I borrowed the BindableTransition class:

```
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
* A simple Transition thats fraction property can be bound to any other
* properties.
* 
* @author hendrikebbers
* 
*/
public class BindableTransition extends Transition {

private DoubleProperty fraction;

public BindableTransition(Duration duration) {
    fraction = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    setCycleDuration(duration);
}

@Override
protected final void interpolate(double frac) {
    fraction.set(frac);
}

public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty fractionProperty() {
    return fraction;
}
}
```

This is a class that I took from [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com/documentation.html), so I have no credit for its creation. The original author, as written in the class itself, is hendrikebbers. I want to thank him/her and the AquaFX team for making available the source code, without which I'd be lost.

As you can see, ScrollBarSkin2 has the addEvents method, which is tasked to add certain events to certain components from skin. Largely, the animations are treated there. The heaviest problem of this code appears when I try to make the thumb to move smoothly once the user click on the track, or the arrow buttons. I just could not implement such behavior, because I have no idea how to do it. I've tried to override the handleControlPropertyChanged method (from BehaviorSkinBase), trying to create a proper positionThumb method. Unfortunately this was not possible because I need some ScrollBarSkin properties in order to properly position the thumb. Such properties would be, for example, trackPos and trackLenght, reserved to be calculated and used only in ScrollBarSkin.

### CONCLUSION

I can then conclude that I do not know what else to do. It is very annoying that Oracle provide JavaFX technology limiting its use (at least this is what appears). Appears to be no documentation on the [study site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) of JavaFX about more advanced customization. The documents on editing and creating custom controls in JavaFX existing on internet talk about the simple customization via CSS, not mentioning how we can implement more advanced features (such as animation of their substructures) within the skin. It makes me so frustrated, after all I see great potential in this technology (incomparable to Swing) and still not have the ability to use this feature.

At the most, I felt myself powerless not knowing what to do. I wish someone responsible for developing JavaFX and documentation take notion of certain limitations that are appearing to us. The existing books on the subject are completely outdated, and if not, they do not say anything more than the existing content [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) (also).

### QUESTION

I do not know where to turn to talk about these kinds of things, but I would like someone to tell me that I'm customizing my controls in the wrong way, and that I must correct some lines of code for any reason whatsoever. After all, JavaFX 8 will be fully launched on March 18. Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. If I am not doing anything wrong, what needs to be done for this to be notified to the developers of JavaFX?

Thank you for your attention.

### EDIT

Some people do not really understand what I wanted to show here. I wanted to demonstrate that there is *apparently some need* for that part of the JavaFX API becomes public. I said that because *I cannot create a simple custom scroll bar*. So I'm guessing for the other side. Is there really a need to leave part of the API public? It was then that I finally could ask:

**Am I doing the customization of controls in a wrong way? If I am, can anyone correct me?**

Simple as that. The huge text post here was proof that I wanted to show, A plus B, that I had to come here to ask this, possibly something that for some people this may be a silly thing. *In other words* ... I demonstrated how I'm customizing my scroll bar (*the source code of my problem*). And then I asked: "Hey, can anyone help me on this? Thank you". I have come not to teach how to customize components, came to show how I'm doing (which apparently seems to be the wrong way or not).

Despite having already accepted the answer of a user, my doubts still exist. Anyway, [I put the same question in the Oracle JavaFX community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3526592), as sugested. And unfortunately things take time to work there (I know that the vast majority is busy working).

Comment: This is extremely intimidating.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, good, I was afraid it was just me who thought that... This reads more like a blog post rather than a question for SO

Comment: @DrydenLong Don't worry, it's not just you.

Comment: @Loa `s/.*/I found a JavaFX issue, who do I tell\?`? Have you tried their [issue tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/)? (Via [home page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/community/index.html) - also states "Instructions on how to submit bug reports or feature requests are available in the [FAQ section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#12)."). They also have a forum for discussion.

Comment: (I also suspect this may be appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com but I am not sure.)

Comment: My intentions were to make my final question something clear and understandable. I always see how important it is to demonstrate the way we arrive at the need to ask for help. It's hard for me to pick a place to ask certain things. I knew someone would compare my question with something more complex, such as a post on a blog. I do not have a blog, I'm just a student who wants to work one day. I apologize for making you lose some time.

Comment: Regarding the fact that the problem which I'm going to be an issue or not, I actually have no idea. I may be going through my fault, through my inability, and not a "defect" of language. Anyway, I'll try posting this in the Oracle community. Wanted to share it with you here... Did not mean to intimidate or offend anyone ... forgive me.

Comment: If the moderators wish, feel comfortable removing my question. I'm going elsewhere to demonstrate what is happening (as suggested). Thank you.

Comment: @Loa SO is mostly community moderated, questions require votes to close -- a moderator would not intervene unless a post was completely inappropriate. I suspect this will eventually be closed, not because of the quality, but because it is categorically off-topic here. Feel free to come back with specific coding problems and issues, though!

Comment: A good place to talk with the developers is the mailing list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev

Comment: I haven't read the full question, but note the difference between API and implementation detail. It's recommended to keep things you don't want to maintain in a backwards compatible way hidden. (E.g. OSGi even provides mechanisms to enforce this.) Is there useful code in the hidden code? Sure! But from an API maintainer point of view you have to limit to what you commit yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> If I am not doing anything wrong, what needs to be done for this to be notified to the developers of JavaFX?

From the [community section on the JavaFX home page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/community/index.html) (emphasis mine):

> The OTN [JavaFX Forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1385) is a great place to post, answer, and review
>   issues related to JavaFX.
>
> **The [Jira bug tracking system](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) is the place where you want to report
>   issues with JavaFX, or file a feature request. Instructions on how to
>   submit bug reports or feature requests are available in the [FAQ section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#12).**

You asked:

> What Oracle expects of us?

I'm presuming they expect you to go through their traditional contact channels, which the developers do read and consider.

Your post is well-written (er... probably... at least it's well-formatted), but you may wish to divide it into smaller, more bite-sized issues or summarize and provide details as-requested in order to make it easier to parse and respond to your concerns.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look there. And sorry for the inconvenience.